# Is container of containers a bad design?

Tags: c++, containers

I need a container of containers like:

```
class Widget {
  ...
};
...
std::vector<std::list<Widget> > widgets;
```

Because STL containers copy objects in them, and copy a container is not a cheap operation, I think this container of containers may leads to really bad efficiency and therefore a bad design.
I want to know if I am right. And if it is, should I use container of container pointers or something else?
Thanks

### p.s.

Thanks for you guys, and now I know whether it's a bad design or not depends on how I use it.

So if I know how many `list`(at most) would be inserted into `vector` and then use `vector::reserve` to avoid `vector`reallocation and after that I just query about objects in it, this may be a good design.

On the other hand, if I need insert `list` into the `vector` every now and then, this may leads to really bad efficiency.

Am I right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is not bad design. It is the way you use it that can be bad design. If your code requires frequent deep copying and you implement `std::vector<std::list<Widget> *> widgets`, but still require a deep copy, there isn't much difference with what you are doing.

If for example, you are querying some member of the `list`s in the vector very frequently, this may actually be good design because of the memory proximity due to the compactness of the vector.

Modern compilers with C++11 support that has move semantics usually move data instead of copying data. So I will not be too concerned about vector relocation or shifting. 'Moving' can still be done by older compilers using `std::swap` whenever it makes more sense than copying.

Comment: Thank you. In fact I concern about the efficiency not because I may deep copy the objects, but because STL may do this like when `vector` reallocate the `list`s in it.

Comment: @kkpattern the deep copying in reallocate is the main bottleneck of reallocating a vector of lists. That's one of the places where C++11 just optimizes the hell out of it since it just moves things over to a new buffer instead of copying them, effectively reducing the capacity growth operation to N shallow copies and one buffer alloc.

Comment: For older compilers it depends on implementation if each element is swapped instead of copied.

Answer (score 1):

No why would it?

Used correctly they won't be a bottleneck more than a 'simple' STL container would be in the first place.

Used wrongly (design wise) they will of course do as you say and act horribly inefficiently.

For your specific problem, you might want to store pointers instead of objects as data.

Comment: I also think pointers is a solution. But when comes to pointers, there are always dangers like memory leak. Thank you anyway.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that the answer to your design question mostly depends on the particularities of your project which we cannot see. Do you need to store values (and manage the life-time of the widgets) or only references?

Note that std::vector only copies elements when you copy the vector. Otherwise, when you only need to increase the vector capacity, it uses elements move constructors which are typically cheap.

Comment: Sorry for didn't post my project cause there are too mush lines. I have this question because my `std::list<Widget>` store values and can be large. So I think when I insert a new `list` into `vector` and cause the `vector` to expand which will reallocate all the objects in it, it will leads to very bad efficiency